# Using VBA to email multliple recipients and copy and paste into body

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I want to take an excel file and create emails.  The file could have multiple rows with the same email address.  I want to create One email for each unique address and for the rows that have the same address create a table to copy and paste into the email.

I am new to VBA but have created code that loops the Excel file to create emails, however, I need help with modifying the code to only look at unique addresses and creating the table.

The code I have now is below:

```
  Sub SendEmail()
  'Uses late binding
  Dim OutlookApp As Object
  Dim MItem As Object
  Dim cell As Range
  Dim Subj As String
  Dim Rname As String
  Dim EmailAddr As String
  Dim Rdate As String
  Dim Ramount As String
  Dim Vendor As String
  Dim CHCPName As String
  Dim HCPLast As String
  Dim Repname As String
  Dim Msg As String
    'Dim FName As String
  'Dim FLoc As String

  'Create Outlook object
  Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")


  'Loop through the rows
  For Each cell In Columns("A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "*@*" Then
      'Get the data
      EmailAddr = cell.Value
      Subj = "Meals with HCPs"
      Repname = cell.Offset(, 1)
      Rname = cell.Offset(, 2)
      Rdate = cell.Offset(, 3)
      Ramount = cell.Offset(, 4).Text
      Vendor = cell.Offset(, 5)
      CHCPName = cell.Offset(, 6)
      'FName = cell.Offset(, 9)
      'FLoc = cell.Offset(, 10)



     'Compose message
      Msg = "Dear " & Repname & ","
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "In a recent review of expense report transactions for Federal Open Payments/Sunshine report, we"
      Msg = Msg & "  noticed that an incorrect expense type was selected for one or more of your meetings. On the following "
      Msg = Msg & "report, you selected an incorrect expense type of " & "<b>Meals w/non HCPs out of office.</b>   It appears that there were HCPs present during the meeting(s)."
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "Please make sure that going forward, you select a correct expense type for all meetings with HCPs " & "<b>(Example: Meal w/HCP out Office-Non-Promo).</b>"
      Msg = Msg & " We need to ensure that we are reporting correct information.  Please note that future violations could result "
      Msg = Msg & " in notification to your manager.  If you have any questions, please let me know."
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "<b>Expense Report Details:</b>"
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "<b>Report Name:  </b>" & Rname
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "<b>Date:  </b>" & Rdate
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "<b>Amount: </b>" & Ramount
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "<b>Vendor Name:  </b>" & Vendor
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "<b>HCP Name(s):  </b>" & CHCPName
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "Regards"
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "Sunil Kumar"
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "Manager"
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "sunil.utleyd@.com"
      Msg = Msg & "<br/>"
      Msg = Msg & "+1(817)615-2333"

      'Create Mail Item and send it
      Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem
      With MItem
        .to = EmailAddr
        .Subject = Subj
        .HTMLBody = Msg
        'Add Atttachments here if you would like
        '.Attachments.Add FLoc & FName


        .Save 'to Drafts folder
        '.Send does not work due to Macro Security Settings for Alcon.  Must send using Outlook
      End With
    End If
  Next
  Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: If the only thing that changes is the email, you can either add the column into an array or dictionary to help you remove duplicate addresses that way.  Then use `For Each Addr in YourArr` to generate the emails.

Answer (score 0):

As @K.Davis indicated, you can use a Dictionary or Collection to test for duplicates.  Here I use an ArrayList.

Ideally a subroutine should perform 1 task.  You should break large subroutines up into smaller ones that perform specific tasks.  This will make debugging your code much easier.

---

```
Sub SendEmail()
'Uses late binding
    Dim list As Object, OutlookApp As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim HTMLBody As String

    'Create Outlook object
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    'Loop through the rows
    For Each cell In Columns("D").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.value Like "*@*" And Not list.Contains(cell.value) Then
            list.Add cell.value
            HTMLBody = getMessageBody(cell.Offset(, 1), cell.Offset(, 2), cell.Offset(, 3), cell.Offset(, 4).Text, cell.Offset(, 5), cell.Offset(, 6))
            EmailAddr = cell.value
            CreateEmail OutlookApp, cell.value, "Meals with HCPs", HTMLBody
        End If
    Next
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub

Sub CreateEmail(OutlookApp As Object, EmailAddr As String, Subject As String, HTMLBody As String)
    Dim MItem As Object
    Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)              'olMailItem
    With MItem
        .to = EmailAddr
        .Subject = Subj
        .HTMLBody = Msg

        .Save 'to Drafts folder
    End With
End Sub

Function getMessageBody(Repname As String, Rname As String, Rdate As String, Ramount As String, Vendor As String, CHCPName As String)
    Dim Msg As String
    Msg = "Dear " & _
          Repname
    Msg = Msg & "<br/><br/>" & _
          "In a recent review of expense report transactions for Federal Open Payments/Sunshine report, we " & _
          "noticed that an incorrect expense type was selected for one or more of your meetings. On the following " & _
          "report, you selected an incorrect expense type of " & _
          "<b>Meals w/non HCPs out of office.</b> " & _
          "It appears that there were HCPs present during the meeting(s)."
    Msg = Msg & "<br/><br/>" & _
          "Please make sure that going forward, you select a correct expense type for all meetings with HCPs " & _
          "<b>(Example: Meal w/HCP out Office-Non-Promo).</b> " & _
          "We need to ensure that we are reporting correct information.  Please note that future violations could result " & _
          "in notification to your manager.  If you have any questions, please let me know."
    Msg = Msg & "<br/><br/><b>Expense Report Details:</b>" & _
          "<br/><br/><b>Report Name:  </b>" & _
          Rname
    Msg = Msg & "<br/><br/><b>Date:  </b>" & _
          Rdate
    Msg = Msg & "<br/><br/><b>Amount: </b>" & _
          Ramount
    Msg = Msg & "<br/><br/><b>Vendor Name:  </b>" & _
          Vendor
    Msg = Msg & "<br/><br/><b>HCP Name(s):  </b>" & _
          CHCPName
    Msg = Msg & "<br/><br/>Regards<br/><br/>Sunil Kumar<br/>Manager<br/>" & _
          "sunil.utleyd@.com<br/>+1(817)615-2333"
    getMessageBody = Msg
End Function
```